# update method in Controller module is having two arguments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

When we create controller via `php artisan make:model ModelName -crm` in Laravel 10, the controller module created has `update` method which takes two arguments.

```
public function update(Request $request, Student $student)
```

My web.php route

```
Route::resource('students', StudentController::class);
```

When we post data from `edit.blade.php` page, as far as I have understood, here `$request` have the form data in `array` format whereas `$student` have the form data as `object`.
So, what is the use of two parameters? Please clarify and also correct if my understanding is wrong. Thank You.

Comment: In the routes, you need to have the `{student}` because of `$student`. This is dependency injection

Comment: Both `$request` and `$student` are "injected" into the method via Laravel processes. For `Request $request`, see [Accessing the Request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#accessing-the-request). For `Student $student`, see [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding) (and yes, they can be combined; `update()` uses both Request injection to access the input from the form and Model Binding injection to know which Model instance it should be updating)

Comment: Lastly, `Route::resource()` creates a bunch of routes behind the scenes: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller, including `/students/{student}`, which links up to `update(Request $request, Student $student)` using the logic above 

Comment: @user4221591 any more question that didn't anwser/understand?

Comment: Thank you every one for the comments. I did `dd($request, $student);` and found that `$request` contains edited data from the form whereas `$student` contains data from the database.

Comment: ^ That's correct  For additional learning, your statement *"`$request` have the form data in `array` format whereas `$student` have the form data as `object`"* is somewhat correct, but `$request` can give you the input as an Object would `$request->name`, or a method, `$request->input('name')`, or an Array `$request->input()['name']`, and `$student`, being a Model, allows either, i.e. `$student->name` or `$student['name']` would both return the Student's name. Laravel is pretty helpful in being flexible on Object vs Array access.